# How to use string concatenation with a HYPERLINK in Google Sheets / Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-spreadsheets

I am attempting to create a cell with a concatenated string comprised of other cells, with a hyperlink at the end. It looks something like this:

```
=(C308 & CHAR(10) & HYPERLINK("https://google.com", "Link to Google"))
```

However, this results in the "Link to Google" text not being a hyperlink, but a plain string.

How do I get it to show up as a hyperlink?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know there is no way to only make one part of the string within a cell a hyperlink and have the rest be regular text. However, one way in which you can make it **look** like that is by first in the hyperlink like below:

```
=HYPERLINK("https://google.com",C308 & CHAR(10) & "Link to Google")
```

This will make the entire content of the cell a hyperlink. You can then change the colour and format of everything that comes before "Link to Google" to look like regular text.